# Storing multiple settings for multiple users in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 to store the account settings for multiple accounts (each user account will have a set of settings). These settings could have any number of fields (has not been completely set and could grow) but each user account will have the same set of settings (different values of course).

Is it better (faster with a smaller footprint and more efficient) to:

1. give each setting its own column and each row to a user? keep in mind that there could be hundreds of settings variables. (i.e. userid, setting1, setting2, setting3...etc)
2. Relate each individual setting to a user and making it a name value pair table
   (i.e.  userid, settingsName, settingValue)

Comment: You are using SQL Server, not SQL. Drives me mad when people call it just SQL!

Comment: Though I like @bummi 's answer, You should always test it yourself, as performance differs from one system to another (due to different data, number of CPUs and parallelism, indexes, etc.)

Comment: @Phil Sorry about that I didn't even realize that I had done that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already maintainability will ask for a structure like shown below.
An additional set of templates would support fast capture of new data (Structure like UserSettings with a templateid instead of userid)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ValueType] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserSettings](
    [userid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [settingsid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [sql_variant] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserSettings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [userid] ASC,
    [settingsid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Thank you, Makes a lot of sense. I think that's what I'll do.